# FSharpPlus does not appear to have a generic `tail` function

Tags: f#, f#+

While there is a `tryHead` and `head`, as in `Seq.tryHead` and `Seq.head`, there is no corresponding `tail` function, as in `Seq.tail`, in the `FSharpPlus` generic functions library. Am I missing something or is this an oversight.

It may be useful for there to also be a generic `Empty` value or predicate as well, I think.

Comment: I missed this question, I think you should always tag with [F#] otherwise I and many other users will miss the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can [open an issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/issues/new) suggesting those functions.

Anyway, if you want a generic tail, you can always do `skip 1` or `drop 1` if you don't want exceptions.

Regarding `Empty` there is a generic function/constant called `empty`.